# Design pattern for allowing functions to accept generic types

Tags: c#, generics, design-patterns

I've got two classes:

```
public abstract class Uniform<T>
public class UniformMatrix4 : Uniform<Matrix4>
```

(So far....there will be more that implement different types)

And now lets say I want to write a function that will accept any uniform object... but I can't do that because there is no class called `Uniform`, only the generic `Uniform<T>`. So what's the best approach to solving this problem?

1. Make `Uniform<T>` implement `IUniform`
2. Make `Uniform<T>` extend `Uniform`
3. Make all my functions that accept a Uniform to be generic too so that they can take a `Uniform<T>` directly?

Comment: Which version of C# are you using?  Have you considered the Dynamic type?

Comment: When there is no class called Uniform, how can exist a Uniform object?

Comment: Without knowing anything about the class's purpose, or it's abstract method signatures, it's difficult to give a proper answer here. #3 seems the obvious answer though.

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt: C# 4. No.. I didn't consider dynamic. Will read that blog post, but I prefer type safety wherever possible.

Comment: @RezaArab: By "Uniform object" I was referring to the concept of a uniform object, not any specific type defined in C#.

Comment: @MarkH: If you want more context, I'm building a wrapper for this guy: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLSL_Uniform

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make your methods generic as well, and you're good.

Note that you always have the choice of using all generic type arguments on the function if needed, like this:

```
public void MyMethod<TUniform, T>(TUniform uniform) where TUniform: Uniform<T> {...}
```

The compiler will usually infer the type arguments on his own whenever you have a parameter, so that the call in fact looks like a normal method invocation in the C# source code:

```
UniformMatrix4 uniform;
MyMethod(uniform); // the types of the generic functions are inferred
```

Comment: This is what I'd do. In Mono under Ubuntu 11.10, I couldn't get it to infer pretty simple argument types and ended up with an ugly invocation: `Run<Uniform<String>, String>(someClass);`

Comment: @JimSchubert, type inference only works on arguments, not on return types, since the return type is not part of the method signature (which is also the reason why you cannot have overloads only differing in the return type). In those cases you must specify the types, but there is a workaround: make the result an `out` argument.

Comment: Hang on... why would you want to declare it like this instead of what Domenic suggests in his answer? This seems more verbose -- what's the benefit?

Comment: @Mark, you get the exact type at compile time. This enables additional scenarios such as adding a new type constraint to create new instances, or use it as strongly typed return value or out argument.

Comment: @Lucero: Hrm...why wouldn't `Uniform<T>` be "the exact type"? If `T` is known at compile time, then `Uniform<T>` should be known. That's weird. I'll keep this in mind though, if the compiler yells at me :D

Comment: @Mark, no, in your example `Uniform<Matrix4>` is a supertype of `UniformMatrix4`. Take the example with the method returning that: `UniformMatrix4 uniform = MyMethod()` will only work if the method returns a `UniformMatrix4`, but not when it returns a `Uniform<Matrix4>`, because you can have any number of other types deriving from `Uniform<Matrix4>` - or you could also directly instantiate that if it isn't abstract. Therefore `Uniform<T>` is not good enough, it cannot exactly represent any type inherited from `Uniform<>` - which is what I mean by "exact type".

Comment: @Lucero the return type of my invocation was `void` and setup exactly as your answer. I use this pattern a lot, but I usually tend to write out the more verbose method invocation and avoid type inference. The type inference may be a limitation of Mono under Ubuntu.  I've had nothing but issues with the Ubuntu repo for Mono.

Comment: @JimSchubert, I had issues with generics in Mono before (type constraints using other generic type parameters, so-called naked type constraints don't work properly) as well. On the MS stack this all works very well.

Answer (score 3):

Admittedly intimidated to post this answer, but think it may be correct:

```
 public static Uniform<dynamic> MyMethod(dynamic myObject) { 
      //do stuff    
      return uniform;
    }
```

Here is a Dino Esposito blog on the topic:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff796227.aspx

Cheers,

Matt

Comment: I probably just don't get it, but how is this relevant?  Maybe expanding on `//do stuff` would help me?

Comment: Oh hang on, if you refer to the `myObject` fields by name, you reconstruct them into a `Uniform<dynamic>`?  If that's the case (or not) perhaps you could expand this answer, I'm quite curious?

Comment: Well, again--a little intimidated contributing to a conversation with all of you uber reputation folks, but what I have been doing is something like this: let's say that I want to use a generic method to construct an object of unknown type at runtime, I would create a new ExpandoObject (dynamic myObject = new ExpandoObject();) and then either populate it's properties explicitly (myObject.Name = "Matt";) or, in the case of a Linq query, I instantiate an IDictionary when looping through the data returned (var item = myObject as IDictionary<String, object>; item[SomeKey] = SomeValue;).  Thanks.

Comment: I don't believe that `Uniform<dynamic>` can be casted to or from a specific type, say, `Uniform<Matrix4>` from the example here. One could use `dynamic` everywhere, but one of the benefits of a pure generic solution compared to a solution involving `dynamic` is that you have full type safety, checking and efficiency at compile time.

Comment: BUT as Mark says, he wants to stick with type-safe methods, so my answer, which uses duck-typing, won't work for him.

Answer (score 2):

```
public void MyMethod<T>(Uniform<T> uniform) { ... }
```

Comment: Yes... that's option #3. Can you explain why this is preferable? The thing I don't like about this is that you're introducing `T` which is only used once in the function signature and then never again. It won't be used for anything else

Comment: @Mark, the type variable `T` here is scoped to the method, not to the class. It doesn't hurt at all and has typically no additional runtime cost associated to it (assuming that `T` is always a reference type).

Comment: I know it's scoped to the method..just saying though. There's 3 options here and I'm trying to figure out which is best.

Comment: @Mark, unless you need that non-generic base class or interface anyways I'd go for the generic approach. Non-generic base classes or an interface is for instance required if you want to have a strongly typed collection of those which may hold different closed `Uniform<>` type instances.

Comment: This is preferable because it is the idiomatic, straightforward, type-safe approach. Why would you do anything different?

Comment: @Domenic: Just checking :) I wasn't sure. I see a lot of people implementing strange patterns...using interfaces and stuff where I didn't think they were necessary. Was wondering if there was some benefit going that route that I wasn't seeing.